# Как посчитать размеры окна при использовании grid?

Tags: python, tkinter

Как посчитать размеры окна при использовании grid? Сейчас приложение(тулбар) находится в вертикальном положении, позиция окна считается из размера экрана и заданного мной размера иконки. вертикальный размер окна зависит от количества иконок (может менятся). в горизонтальном положении все будет зависеть от количества иконок. могу ли я не привязываться к реальным размерам, а сделать именно привязку по правой части экрана или просто отображать окно с минусовым значением размера?
 Самое главное, нужно это сделать средствами самого python!
 пробовал вывести текущий размер экрана командой print(root.window_width()), выводит 200х200, видимо значение по умолчанию.

Comment: Возможно вы пытаетесь вывести `print(root.window_width())` до того как окно фактически создано (до `root.mainloop()`). Попробуйте добавить `root.update()` перед выводом размера. Размер не может быть минусовым. Ставьте позицию по горизонтали как `ширина_экрана - ширина окна`.

Comment: ширина окна у меня распознается как 200 (по умолчанию, а не фактическая...)

Answer (score 1):

Все оказалось гораздо проще.

Следующие команды **обязательно** нужно ставить после `self.show()` главного окна/фрейма

```
print(root.winfo_width())
print(root.winfo_height())
```

Мое содержимое `self.show()`:

```
root.geometry('{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(size_wx, size_wy, pos_wx, pos_wy))
self.grid()
```

Comment: winfo выдавал значения по умолчанию (200х200) потому, что я запрашивал значения раньше чем их туда отправлял (вообще упустил из виду это построение окна)